# Could not Append to select tag by javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, select, model, tags, fill

I am doing an mvc 5 project and I have cart view and I have 2 deopdownlist named country and state in it and  when it is run the country model fill country dropdownlist and now I want to fill state dropdownlist onchange of country dropdownlist so I used code below to do this but it does not work successfully.i debug this code it works correctly the only problem is that this code can not append to state dropdownlist.I dont know what to do

```
@model IEnumerable<NewMVCWebApp.Models.Country>
<script>
    function f11() {
        var a = $("#se option:selected").text();
        var b = $("#se option:selected").index();
         $.ajax({           
            url: "/State/GetStates",
            data: { a: a, b: b },
            type:"post",
            success: function (value) {
                cities = JSON.parse(value);
                $("#ss").html("");
                $("#ss").append("<option>--- please select---</option>");
                $.each(cities, function (idx, city) {
                    $("#ss").append("<option value='" + city.ID + "'>" + city.name + "</option>")
                })

            },
            error: function () {
                $("#lbl").html("Error in Ajax...!");
            }
        })

      }
</script>

<div class="tabs-b">

    <ul>
        <li>estimate</li>

    </ul>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>enter destination</p>
            <p class="required">
                <label for="sha">Country</label>
                <select id="se" name="Country" onchange="f11()">
                    <option>--- please select ---</option>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <option value="@item.ID">@item.name</option>
                    }
                </select>

            </p>
            <p class="required">
                <label>region</label>
                <select id="ss"></select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="shc">post code</label>
                <input type="text" name="shc" id="shc" required="">
            </p>
            <p class="link-c">@*<a href="./">get</a>*@</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the action in the controller

```
public string  GetStates(string a,string b)
{
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<state> states = _context.states.Where(x => x.IDK == Idk).ToList();
return js.Serialize(states.Select(x => new { ID = x.ID, name = x.name }));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller change method type to JsonResult

```
 public JsonResult  GetStates(int index)
    {
        JsonResult json = new JsonResult();
        json.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
        json.Data = _context.states.Where(x => x.IDK == index).ToList();
        return json;
    }
```

and in html file

```
function f11() {
        var index = $("#se option:selected").val();
         $.ajax({           
            url: "/State/GetStates",
            data: { index: index },
            type:"post",
            success: function (value) {
                var result  = "";
                $("#ss").append("<option>--- please select---</option>");
                $.each(value, function (index, city) {
                     result += "<option value='" + city.ID + "'>" + city.name + "</option>";

                });
                $("#ss").append(result);

            },
            error: function () {
                $("#lbl").html("Error in Ajax...!");
            }
        })

      }
```

Comment: thanks for your help but it does not work . I debug this code it works correctly and jquery and json again work correctly but JUSTTTTTTTTTTTTT can not appent in final step.I dont know what to do.please help me

Comment: What if move <script> to the bottom ??

Comment: I tried Your code.that was perfect the same as my code. but both can not append